# Setting up Controller for a reservations app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am learning and building my first app with Ruby on Rails by cloning and adjusting an existing project. I got stuck in the writing a controller and hope that someone has a tip to help me out.

**Context**
I am building a trainings platform: Users can design a training, these trainings can be given on several dates (I call these trainingsessions 'thrills'), (other) users can subscribe to these thrills with reservations.

[Conceptualization of models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyw6E.png)

**Complication**
I got the users, trainings and reservations model running now but I want to add the thrills model in between (I know this is not the easiest way, but I followed a training that did not include the thrills model). I setup the model and a simple view where a trainer should be able to add thrills to an existing training (in trainings/edit). Unfortunately after a day of trying I have not managed to do so, I keep getting:

> NoMethodError in ThrillsController#create
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `thrills' for nil:NilClass): (line 16)

My TrainingsController for def edit looks like

```
  def edit
       if current_user.id == @training.user.id
          @photos = @training.photos
          @thrill = @training.thrills.create(thrill_params)
          @thrills = @training.thrills
       else
          redirect_to root_path, notice: "Je hebt hier helaas geen toegang tot"
      end
  end

  def update
        if @training.update(training_params)

          if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
              @training.photos.create(image: image)
            end
          end

          @thrill = @training.thrills.create(thrill_params)
          @thrills = @training.thrills

          @photos = @training.photos

          redirect_to edit_training_path(@training), notice: "Updated..."
        else
          render:edit
        end
  end
```

And my ThrillsController looks like

```
class ThrillsController < ApplicationController

    def create

        @thrill = @training.thrills.create(thrill_params)
        redirect_to @thrill.training, notice: "Je thrill is aangemaakt!"        
    end

    private
    def thrill_params
        params.require(:thrill).permit(:trilldate, :thrillhr, :thrillmin, :training_id)
    end

end
```

And my form to add a thrill in views/thrills/_form.html.erb which is rendered in views/trainings/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@training.thrills.new]) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :thrillhr, placeholder: "Uur", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :training_id, value: @training.id %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The full code of the app can be found here https://github.com/chrisrutte/musc

**Question**
I'm obviously doing something simple wrong here, so I hope someone can provide me the hint how to save new thrills in my Thrills model.

If any more information is needed, don't hestitate to ask me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should assign objects then use them, another way it won't work. Which line of code is producing an error?

Comment: Yeah, the full stack trace would be helpful. you're calling a thrills method in a lot of places so there are a lot of places where something could be nil that you don't think is nil.

Comment: Just added the line. Thanks for your interest! @AndreyS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets look at what the models for this kind of setup would look like:

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thrills
  has_many :users, through: :thrills
end

class Thrills < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :training
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thrill
  has_one :training, though: :thrill
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :thrills, through: :reservations
  has_many :trainings, through: :thrills
end
```

Make sure you read the [Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) as this is quite complex.

Notice that Reservation works as a join model.

Reservation also has an indirect relation to Training. This is to avoid having duplicate foreign keys on several levels. The same applies to the User model. The main reason is that ActiveRecord will only write the foreign key in once place!

When setting up the routes you will most likely want [to use nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :trainings, shallow: true do
  resources :thrills
end
```

We can then setup the controller.

```
class ThrillsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_training!, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :set_thrill!, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /trainings/:training_id/thrills/new
  def new
    @thrill = @training.thrills.new
  end

  # POST /trainings/:training_id/thrills
  def create
    @thrill = @training.thrills.new(thrill_params)

    if @thrill.save
      redirect_to @thrill
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # GET /trainings/:training_id/thrills
  def index
    @thrills = @training.thrills
  end

  # this is not nested.
  # GET /thrills/:id
  def show
  end 

  # this is not nested.
  # GET /thrills/:id/edit
  def edit
  end 

  # this is not nested.
  # PUT|PATCH /thrills/:id
  def update
    if @thrill.update(thrill_params)
      redirect_to @thrill
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end 

  # ...

  private 
    def set_training!
      @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
    end

    def set_thrill!
      @thill = Thrill.joins(:training).find(params[:id])
      @training = @thill.training
    end

    def thrill_params
        params.require(:thrill)
              .permit(:trilldate, :thrillhr, :thrillmin, :training_id)
    end
end
```

And lets setup the form:

```
<%= form_for( [@training, @thrill] ) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :thrillhr, placeholder: "Uur", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Since we want to pass the `training_id` though the form `action` attribute and not in the form body we use  `form_for( [@training, @thrill] )` which will give us the path `/trainings/6/thrills` for example.

However for our edit form we want `/thrills/1` instead. So lets fix that:

```
<%= form_for( @thrill.new_record? ? [@training, @thrill] : @thrill ) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: There are a lot of other idiosyncrasies in your app - you should be using nested attributes to create photos. Don't preface attributes with the name of the model / table (trilldate, thrillhr)  as its superfluous, very unrailsy and looks stupid.

Comment: In general nested resources are probably the hardest part of rails for beginners - make sure you read through the guides articles.

Comment: This really helped me. Especially the part to set_training! and the use of through now make sense to me. The sad part is that the code still gives the error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass): This gives me the feeling it still doesn't recognize the line in Thrillscontroller def new. Here the class @thrill should be set. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your tips, they are highly appreciated :)

Comment: Check the log from your rails server and make sure the request is being matched  to the expected controller.

Comment: Yes! That helped me. I was rendering the form in trainings/edit and that was not the location the controller was written. Thanks a lot!